# not getting the subject info or the current row information in body of the email when using google-apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, message, geturl

I am having problems with getting the current row information to be included in my email message when the email address that I'm sending to is listed on another spreadsheet.  It works when I define the email address within the script.

I have 3 spreadsheets.  The spreadsheet sheet names are Team, Issues, and Watchers.  The Issues spreadsheet is the main sheet.  When a new row is added on the Issues spreadsheet, column 34 is marked as "Ready to Email". If Column 34 is set to "Ready to Email" and Column 35 is not marked as "SENT", then I want to send an email notification using the email addresses listed on the WATCHERS spreadsheet then mark column 35 as "SENT".  In the body of the email I want to include the URL of the main spreadsheet Issues spreadsheet) and information from the current row. I also want to include the value that is in cell "B2"on the TEAM spreadsheet.   If no email addresses exist in the WATCHERS spreadsheet I want to mark column 35 as "No EMAIL ADDRESS EXIST".

Again, I'm able to send emails but the problem is that I'm not getting the subject info or the current row information in body of the email.  Here is my script....

```html
function sendEmail() 
{

  //setup function
  var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Issues");  //the issues spreadsheet
  var StartRow = 2; //first row of data to process
  var LastRow = ActiveSheet.getLastRow();
  var RowRange = LastRow - StartRow + 1;
  var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,35);
  var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();  //getting the values defined in the range of the issues spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //this is so that I can use the getUrl function to get the URL of the ISSUES spreadsheet
 
  for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) 
   
    {
      
      var watchers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Watchers"); //the watchers spreadsheet
      var wdata = watchers.getRange("A2:B" + watchers.getLastRow()).getValues();  //getting the values defined in the range in the watchers spreadsheet
      var team = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Team"); //the team spreadsheet
      var tdata = team.getRange("B2").getValues(); //getting the value defined in cell B2 in the team spreadsheet.
      var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
      var EmailSent = CurrentRow[34];  //the value of column 35 on the issues spreadsheet
      if (CurrentRow[33] == "Ready to Email" && EmailSent!= "sent") 
      {
         wdata.forEach(function(row,CurrentRow,tdata,ss)     //I think this is my problem.  I'm trying to pass in CurrentRow, tdata, and ss so that I can use in my email.
                {

                   var Subject = "New Issue reported:  Issue# " + CurrentRow[3];    //set subject line   
                   var message = "";   
                   message +=                      //CurrentRow, ss, and tdata is not working.
                   "<p><b>A new issue has been reported for </b>" + tdata + "<p><b> Reference the SRD for more details. </b>" + ss.getUrl() + "</p>" +
                   "<p><b>Issue Status:  </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
                   "<p><b>Group:  </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
                   "<p><b>LifeCycle Status:  </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +  
                   "<p><b>Issue Number:  </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
                   "<p><b>Priority:  </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
                   "<p><b>Description:  </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" +
                   "<p><b>Opened By:  </b>" + CurrentRow[10] + "</p>"; 
                    MailApp.sendEmail
                  ({
                        to: row[1],
                        subject: Subject,
                        htmlBody: message,
                  });
                       
  
                });
               
           var setRow = i + StartRow;
        
  
         ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 35).setValue("sent");  //update the row if email is sent
    }  
  }
}
```

Note that for the first line of the message, "ss.getUrl()" is failing with TypeError: Cannot call method "getUrl" of undefined.

This is what the body of the email looks like when I received it.

[image]

Comment: If you will provide images of your spreadsheets I'll be glad to take a look at it. But If I were you I'd probably concat all of the different sheetts of data into one row array.

Comment: Have you tried doing a regular `for` loop instead of `forEach`?